# Beginner level : What is the intuitive meaning and what are the steps to prove for an injective function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

For the proof that  a map is into, it is convenient to use the contrapositive of the definition of one-to-one, namely:
$$ \forall x,y \in X, f(x) = f(y) \rightarrow x = y. $$
where the definition of into (injective) is

Definition : A function $f$ is one-to-one if:
$$  \forall x,y \in X, x \neq y \rightarrow f(x) \neq f(y).$$

SO, b the definition it means that there is only one unique pre-image. 
How are these two (contrapositive and actual definition ) equivalent? My confusion is that when we want to prove that  a map is injective using the contradiction, do we prove by contracdiction that $x = y$ should not hold so that the map becomes into? Can somebody please explain in simple terms what into means and what are the steps to prove?

Comment: The second is just the contrapositive, it always works.

Comment: I know that many textbooks and examples use the contradiction to prove, but I am unable to understand that when we use contradiction to prove that $x=y$ by assuming that $f(x) = f(y)$, how this proves that $x,y$ imply the same point?

Comment: This is no contradiction here, this is prepositional logic.

Comment: Try to see why $f(x)=x$ is injective.

Comment: Do we prove by contracdiction that $x = y$ should not hold so that the map becomes into?

Comment: @simonzackck; You've a typo (pr**e**positional).

Comment: If $x=y$ and $f(x)≠f(y)$ this implies that $f$ is not even a mapping $i.e$ you'r considering that the anticident has more than 1 image.

Comment: Is your question about mappings, or about the rule of contraposition in general? Both?

Comment: @GFauxPas That's the question, I think if the OP knew how to answer, they'd have clarified :)

Comment: @SrishtiM It is not related to contradiction at all. [Contrapositition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) and contradiction are different words. Contraposition states that $A\Rightarrow B\iff \lnot B\Rightarrow \lnot A$. For a proof of this statement see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition).

Comment: I would appreciate if the rule of contraposition is explained followed by how to apply contraposition in injective function. I thought that contraposition = contradiction. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, if you have two sentences $P$ and $Q$, then $$(P \implies Q) \iff (¬Q \implies ¬ P).$$

So: $$(f(x)=f(y) \implies x = y) \iff (x \neq y \implies f(x) \neq f(y)).$$

The idea, however, is just what you said: given a point in the image, there is *only one* pre-image.

Examples:

- $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, given by $f(x) = x^2$ is not injective because $f(2)=f(-2)$ but $2 \neq -2$.
- $g: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, given by $g(x) = 2x$ is injective, because $g(x) = g(y) \implies 2x=2y \implies x = y$.
- $h: \Bbb R_{>0}\to \Bbb R$, given by $h(x)= 2^x$ is injective because $h(x)=h(y) \implies 2^x=2^y \implies \log_22^x =\log_22^y \implies x=y,$ etc.

---

You have two **equivalent** sentences:

**1)** for all $x,y \in {\rm dom}(f)$, $f(x) = f(y)$ implies $x = y$.

**2)** for all $x,y \in {\rm dom}(f)$, $x \neq y$ implies $f(x) \neq f(y)$.

Fixed a function $f$, choose one of the above sentences to study and keep it.

To prove that a function is **not** injective, it is sufficient to find **one** pair of elements $x,y$ such that $f(x) = f(y)$ but $x \neq y$.

To prove that a function **is** injective, you must check one of the senteces above for **all** elements $x,y$. It is usually easier to work with sentence **2)**, since it is *not* sufficient to take particular $x,y$. So about your argument in the comment, it is wrong. You took particular $x,y$ there.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you please clarify the following ? (1) What is the intuitive, english like meaning for the sentence $(P=>Q) <=> ( not Q => not P) $ (2) Thank you for the examples,First example is injective because the contraposition does not hold? but in second example say $g(2) = 4, g(-2) = - 4$. Then, it is injective because $ 4 \neq -4$ and $2 \neq -2$ i.e., the contrapositive is true? To summarize, in order to prove a function to be into we should show that the contrapositve must be true? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I elaborated the answer more, please look at it.

Answer (score 4):

The best explanation I've heard for the meanings of "injective" and "surjective" are

- $f:X\to Y$ is **injective** if for each $y\in Y$, there is **at most** one $x\in X$ with $f(x)=y$
- $f:X\to Y$ is **surjective** if for each $y\in Y$, there is **at least** one $x\in X$ with $f(x)=y$

Naturally, combining them gives

- $f:X\to Y$ is **bijective** if for each $y\in Y$, there is **exactly** one $x\in X$ with $f(x)=y$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you were given an injective function $f : X \to Z$, and you knew from the definition that

$$\text{If } x \neq y, \text{ then }f(x) \neq f(y).$$

Suppose now that somebody hands you the image under $f$ of two things in $X$, and tells you that $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$. You would be forced to conclude that $x_1 = x_2$, wouldn't you? Otherwise, if they were unequal, that would contradict the definition.

In general, any statement of the form

$$\text{If } P \text{ then }Q$$ is equivalent to the *contrapositive*,

$$\text{If $($not } Q) \text{ then $($not }P).$$

In this sense, we can transform the definition of injective:

\begin{align*}
\text{If } x \neq y, \text{ then }f(x) \neq f(y) &\iff \text{If $\big($not } f(x) \neq f(y)\big), \text{ then $\big($not }x \neq y\big)\\
&\iff \text{If } f(x) = f(y), \text{ then }x = y.
\end{align*}

Since these two ways are equivalent, you have two methods to prove a function $f: X \to Z$ is injective:

1. Using strictly the definition, **assume** $x \neq y$ for some $x, y \in X$, and **show** that $f(x) \neq f(y)$.
2. Or, use the contrapositive: **assume** that $f(x) = f(y)$ for some $x, y \in X$, and **show** that $x = y$.

Comment: Thank you for your easy explanation. It will help to make a complete answer if you can kindly put up an example to show how to prove a function to be injective.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prove that a function $f : X \to Y$ is injective, you would have to prove if $f(x)=f(y)$, then $x=y$.

For example, consider the function $f$ that satisfies $f(f(x))=x$ $ \forall x$. In order to prove that it is injective, assume $f(x)=f(y)$. Then, we have $x=f(f(x))=f(f(y))=y$, and we have proven that $x=y$.